# Pandas to_csv with extra zeroes

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some issues reading a csv to a dataframe, then when I convert to csv it will have extra decimals in it.

Currently using pandas 1.0.5 and python 3.7

For example consider the simple example below:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


d = """ticker,open,close
aapl,108.922,108.583
aapl,109.471,110.25
aapl,113.943,114.752
aapl,117.747,118.825
"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=",", header=0, index_col=0)
print(df)
print("\n", df.to_csv())
```

The output is:

```
           open    close
ticker                  
aapl    108.922  108.583
aapl    109.471  110.250
aapl    113.943  114.752
aapl    117.747  118.825

ticker,open,close
aapl,108.92200000000001,108.583
aapl,109.471,110.25
aapl,113.943,114.75200000000001
aapl,117.74700000000001,118.825
```

as you can see there are extra zeroes added to the `to_csv()` output.  If I change the read_csv to have dtype=str like `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=",", dtype=str, header=0, index_col=0)` then I would get my desired output, but I want the dtype to be decided by pandas, to be int64, or float depending on the column values.  Instead of forcing all to be object/str.

Is there a way to eliminate these extra zeroes without forcing the dtype to str?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the float-format argument:

```
d = """ticker,open,close
aapl,108.922,108.583
aapl,109.471,110.25
aapl,113.943,114.752
aapl,117.747,118.825
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=",", header=0, index_col=0)
df.to_csv('output.csv',float_format='%.3f')

#This is how the output.csv file looks:

ticker,open,close
aapl,108.922,108.583
aapl,109.471,110.250
aapl,113.943,114.752
aapl,117.747,118.825
```